# If possible, How to authenticate thin server SPA users through backend REST where nginx role limited to serve static content and proxy Backend REST?

Tags: ajax, rest, authentication, nginx, single-page-application

I am building SPA with thin server architecture (in my case it mean: webserver role restricted to server static content and route xhr with backend REST services):

so far I failed to find any example that provide user authentication scheme that cover my requirements, when it comes to user authentication all what I see webserver (server side code) involved whether its php/nodejs/asp.net..etc.

I want to build the authentication with zero dependency on server side code that belong to webservers:

details:

1. user requested login.html.
2. NGINX served the user request.
3. user supplied credentials and submit.
4. Ajax XHR received by NGINX and routed to the Authentication backend REST service.
5. authentication backend service validated the request and returned response that include session cookie/access token/api key.
6. Ajax XHR received the response through NGINX, then what? how should I proceed? below are current ideas I have:
   a. in many examples (including instagram): window.location.reload();. but in my case reload login.html will not cause NGINX to forward the user to the landing page unless it maintain the authentication logic! so how I can pass this obstacle?
   b. in case I redirect the user to landing.html, NGINX will serve it. but again that's not acceptable because every resource request (except login.html) must be validated first (I mean both authentication and authorization).

I hope the question is clear now. I think if NGINX can be configured to pass every request to the authentication backend REST service before it go to the original destination, big part will be resolved though it might be big overhead for auth service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option here is to use X-Accel-Redirect. This will allow you to pass your requests to the authentication service and then in the authentication service you can run your auth logic and if successful set the X-Accel-Redirect header so that when nginx gets the response it will perform an internal redirect to the resource that you actually want to call. If authentication fails your service can reply with a 401 and not set the header so nginx will provide the proper response to the client.

Your other option, which will be more daunting, is to implement this as a custom Lua module.